# Штандара. Происхождение.

Tags: этимология

Во многих сёлах существует такое понятие как «штандара» (штандар) – это одна из дубовых свай, загнанных в землю под срубом вместо фундамента. Единственная аналогия, всплывающая в моём сознании – штандарт. Интересно узнать, от этого  слова происходит «штандара» или есть что-то ещё?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По созвучию согласных решила посмотреть в немецко-русском словаре.
Вот что нашлось:

**Ständer – "стойка, подпорка, подставка**"... и даже "вешалка".

Похоже, есть прямая смысловая связь со сваями, подпирающими сруб.
Не исключено, что такой способ строительства пошёл от прибывших в Россию (при Петре I) голландцев и немцев.

В Большом Толковом словаре современного украинского языка***  нашлось ещё одно значение, даю в переводе:

**Штандара** – *(диалект.)* **крепкая жердина, шест,** используемый для расширения воза при перевозке снопов, сена и т.п..

Т.е. опять же "дополнительная опора".

---

***) Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - Изд-во "Перун", 2005.

Comment: хорошая версия, сомнительно только, что слово перешло в народный язык, не закрепившись в специальном употреблении и/или профжаргоне. 
  
Хотя, я тут не специалист. Надо будет у строителей поспрашивать.

Comment: О_Леся, вы дали великолепный исчерпывающий ответ! Спасибо большое! Скорее всего, и в украинский язык это слово пришло из немецкого, ведь после войны 1812 года в Украине осталось проживать немало немцев.

Comment: Рада была помочь. ;-)
К тому же, мне и самой интересно раздвигать рамки уже известного. Так что Вам ‒ спасибо за повод!